# Java multiple class addition

Tags: java

This is what ive got so far it does not work i dont know why lol. 
I think i did it the right way i should but why

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package midterm;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author prvillanuevajr
 */
public class Calc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        Myarithmetic m = new Myarithmetic();
        System.out.println("[1] - Add");
        System.out.println("[2] - Subtract");
        System.out.println("[3] - Multiply");
        System.out.println("[4] - Divide");
        System.out.print("CHOOSE: ");
        int choose = s.nextInt();
        switch (choose) {

            case 1:
                System.out.println("ADDITION");
                x = s.nextInt();
                y = s.nextInt();
                m.setX(x);
                m.setY(y);
                m.add();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("INVALID INPUT");
        }
    }
}

public class Myarithmetic {
    private int y;
    private int x;

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public int add(){
        int sum = 0;
        sum = getX()+getY();
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: it does not bring the right answer i dont know why

Comment: Look at the last part does it make sense is that correct?

Comment: In the method `add` you should use `x` and `y`, and not their get methods. It won't fix the problems, but it's a good practice. Also, you can just do `return x + y;`

Comment: I tried to return x+y but when i run the program it wont return any value why is it lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't actually printing the result; you're just calling the `add()` method.

Try:

```
System.out.println(m.add());
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are writing **two public classes within same source file** remove public or write second file into new .java file

Otherwise I'm show you some modification in your program so that it works as per your need:

```
    public class A {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        int x,y;
        System.out.println("1.add  2.subtract");
        System.out.println("Enter your choice: ");
        int choice = sc.nextInt();

        A obj = new A();
        switch(choice){
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Enter two number to add: ");
            x=sc.nextInt();
            y=sc.nextInt();
            obj.add(x,y);
            break;

        case 2:
            /*  Case 2 containts here   */
        }
    }

    public void add(int x, int y){
        int a=x,b=y;
        int answer = a+b;
        System.out.println("Addition is :"+answer);

    }
}
```

Comment: No its not on the same file its in both different class

Comment: I tried to run it yes it works but it wont return any answer when i input two numbers to add;

Comment: What I'm saying is that you are written all this code in single file(source file) with .java extension.